# Kanban-style org file window layout

Tags: org-mode

I would like to create an elisp function to set up a window layout for a single org file, similar to a Kanban layout (Trello, etc).

For each top-line headline, I want to create a separate clone (`clone-indirect-buffer`), narrowed to that specific header.

For example, I might have this file:

```
* Head 1
** Sub-item 2
** Sub-item 3
* Head 2
** Item
* Head 3
** One more
```

The layout can be set up manually with the keystrokes:

- `C-x 3`, `C-x 3`—Create two vertical splits (3 windows)
- `C-x +`—Set equal width for all windows
- `C-x 4 c`, `C-x 4 c`—Make two clones of the buffer
- `C-x n s`, once for each window, on a separate line starting `Head`

The result is three windows, each with a separate subtree—the Kanban layout.

Can anyone suggest where to start with this? I don't have much elisp experience but am happy to learn as I go...thank you!

Comment: Henry, you specifically state that you want to learn how to make an elisp function.  I'll let others address that; I don't know how (yet?).  Incidentally, since you named all those keystrokes, do you know about [Named Keyboard Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html)?  If you expand your sequence of keystrokes to include some navigation commands, record them as a macro, name the macro, and save it in `init.el`, you might not need the elisp function. Maybe this is why I don't know elisp yet. ;)

Comment: @daveloyall thanks for the suggestion—I didn't know about named macros. This looks useful! But, the number of top-level headlines may be different across different files, and I'd like a general way to choose the number of splits, etc...